# If $z_i+z_jz_k$ are real, then $z_1z_2z_3=1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z_j=r(cosφ_j+isinφ_j), r\in R$ for $j=1,2,3$ be different complex numbers.

If the numbers $w_1=z_1+z_2z_3$, $w_2=z_2+z_1z_3$, $w_3=z_3+z_1z_2$ are real, prove that $z_1z_2z_3=1$

I know one solution for this problem, but it just seems too complex. Wonder if there is anything simpler. (i won't post the solution that i know, at least for now)

Comment: Your first sentence seems superfluous aside from the fact that the $z_j$ are complex. (This polar form may come in handy, to be sure, but it's not essential to the statement of the problem...)

Comment: it tells you that they have the same modulus

Comment: You're quite correct, I was being careless. Though if they have the same modulus, then their product being one means it's necessary (though not sufficient) for that modulus to be $1$.

Comment: Actually, it would be helpful if you'd indicate briefly the method you already possess. Otherwise we run the risk of telling you something you already know. (Plus you can post it as an answer and get feedback/comments/rep.)

Comment: This particular method proves that $sin(φ_1+φ_2+φ_3)=0$ with contradiction.

Comment: I added the VERY important information that $z_j$ are different.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is not the "too complex" method you were talking about...

$$
z_j = r(\cos \varphi_j + i \sin \varphi_j) = re^{i\varphi_j}, j=1,2,3
$$

Using the parallelogram rule for addition of complex numbers, $0 = \arg(w_1) = \arg(z_1 + z_2 z_3)=\frac1{2} (\arg z_1 + \arg z_2 z_3) = \frac1{2}(\arg z_1z_2z_3) $.
This implies that $z_1 z_2 z_3 $ is a positive real number.

$$
z_1 z_2 z_3 = r^3e^{i(\varphi_1 + \varphi_2 + \varphi_3)}>0. \\
\therefore \varphi_1 + \varphi_2 + \varphi_3 = 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\because \left|e^{ix}\right| =1, \therefore z_1z_2z_3 = r^3. \\
w_1 = z_1 + \frac{r^3}{z_1}, w_2=z_2 + \frac{r^3}{z_2}, w_3=z_3+\frac{r^3}{z_3}\\
w_j = z_j + r^3z_j^{-1}=r(\cos\varphi_j + i \sin\varphi_j)+r^2(\cos \varphi_j - i \sin \varphi_j)=(r+r^2)\cos \varphi_j + (r-r^2)i \sin \varphi_j, j=1,2,3\\
\Im(w_j)=0\Rightarrow r-r^2 = 0\Rightarrow r=0,1\Rightarrow z_1z_2z_3=0,1.
$$
$\Im(z)$ is the imaginary part of $z$. r can't be zero because the precondition stated that the complex numbers were different values - if it were they would be the same i.e. $z_1 = z_2 = z_3 = 0$.

$$
\therefore z_1z_2z_3 = 1
$$

Comment: Well, this is not the method I was talking about but it's even more complex for me because I can't even understand it :P

Comment: Could you clarify which parts of it are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: I am not familiar with the arg(x) function and also I don't understand those symbols with the three dots you're using.

Comment: Here is an explanation of [the argument function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)). Also, $\therefore$ means "therefore" and $\because$ means "because".

Comment: I don't think the argument of the sum is the average of the arguments unless you know that the two numbers have the same modulus. That is, unless you already know that $r=1$.

Comment: Why would the modulus change it? A diagonal through a parallelogram always bisects the angles it touches - that would naturally include the rhombus case you speak of.